# Create Mixins in Sass files

Tags: html, css, sass

This is my code, I wanted to create mixins in my sass files

```
=shaping($height , $width, $rad, $bg, $color)

height:                     $height

width:                      $width

-webkit-border-radius:      $rad

-moz-border-radius:         $rad

-ms-border-radius:          $rad

background-color:           $bg

border-radius:              $rad

color:                      $color
```

But it has this error when I compile it, and I don't know what's the problem, can anyone help me with these? Is it because of syntax?

`error: properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes or other properties`

Comment: how did you include mixin?

Comment: well i did like this =>.thumb1
    +shaping(120px, 100px, 10%, $brand-dark, $brand-light)

Comment: the syntax for include is incorrect try to add  `.thumb1 { @include shaping(120px, 100px, 10%, $brand-dark, $brand-light) }`

Comment: its not working:( shouldnt we use + to include mixins in a class?

Comment: can you please tell why you use = sign for create mixins? is this a valid syntax in sass? which document are you followed for sass mixin

Comment: sure,im using this site [link]( https://sass-lang.com/guide) and for Mixins it has has a simple example,which used = to create mixins `=border-radius($border-radius)`

Comment: Just a comment on the link from @mona about the equals sign - you only see that syntax in the doc if you switch over to Sass syntax (instead of the default SCSS syntax, which uses things like ```@mixin transform($property)``` instead of ```=transform($property))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=shaping($height, $width, $rad, $bg, $color)
  height: $height
  width: $width
  -webkit-border-radius: $rad
  -moz-border-radius: $rad
  -ms-border-radius: $rad
  border-radius: $rad
  background-color: $bg
  color: $color

.element
  +shaping(50px, 50px, 10px, #000, #fff)
```

After selector, give a line break. E.g.

```
.element
      +shaping
```

Comment: You are right but this syntax is for scss,im using sass and it has a different syntax,that mixins start with equal sign

Comment: Line Break !! that was it ,thanks.now worked for me.such a silly mistake

Comment: Also with line-break. Don't forget 2 space or tab before `+shaping`. [Read More about it](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#multiline_selectors). Also, Accept the question if it solves your problem.

Comment: seems like line-breaks are important in Sass,i will,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me:

```
$brand-dark: #000
$brand-light: #fff

=shaping($height , $width, $rad, $bg, $color)
  height: $height
  width: $width
  -webkit-border-radius: $rad
  -moz-border-radius: $rad
  -ms-border-radius: $rad
  background-color: $bg
  border-radius: $rad
  color: $color

.box
  +shaping(120px, 100px, 10%, $brand-dark, $brand-light)
```